# WPF MVVM Validation Problem using MVVM-Helpers validation attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I'm working on a new C#4.0 / Prism 4 applicaiton using the [JulMar Mvvm-Helpers](http://mvvmhelpers.codeplex.com/) to help with my MVVM implementation.  I have a problem with my validation logic.  In the past, I've been using Prism 2.2 / Enterprise Library Validation Block successfully.  But for this project, I'm trying something new.

My XAML Code is below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DoSomeThing.Views.DoSomeThingView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:JulMar.Windows.Converters;assembly=JulMar.Wpf.Helpers" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:ValidationErrorConverter x:Key="errorConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource errorConverter}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Name="EditGrid" Margin="3">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Name" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Address" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Zip" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Number Of Doors" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Content="Double Number" />


    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Address, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=Zip, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfDoors, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Width="200"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Path=DoubleNumber, Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,41,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

The code to bind the view to the viewmodel is

```
            IRegion region = this._regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];
        var v = new DoSomeThingView();
        var model = new SampleDataModel
            {
                Name = "hello",
                NumberOfDoors = 5,
                Zip = "12345",
                DoubleNumber = 321.12,
                Address = "no where's ville"
            };

        var vm = new SampleDataViewModel { DataModel = model };

        v.EditGrid.DataContext = vm;
        region.Add(v);
```

All the editing logic works as do the validation attributes on the view model.  My problem is with the `bool CanSaveCommand(object param)` function to prevent saving if any validation errors are present.

I do not see how to detect that there are any validation errors present.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I ended up calling the viewmodel validation routine explicitly and checking the result.

My viewmodel inherited from `ValidatingViewModel` base class.  That allows access to the static ValidationManager class as follows -

```
private bool CanSaveExecute(object param)
{
    string v = ValidationManager.Validate(null, this);
    bool b = v.Length == 0;
    return b;
}
```

With the first parameter null, it tests all properties on the viewmodel that have validation attributes.  Then if the returned error message string's length > 0, you can detect that there is a validation error present.